# Pyinstaller PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/user_name/dist/

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Every time I run pyinstaller in the terminal I get the following error:

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/my_username/dist/

Any ideas on solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this by manually deleting all files in the target directory before running Pyinstaller again. Give it a try.

Comment: I have the same issue, but only when I add binaries to my setup. It seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller is probably trying to write files to a directory `/Users/my_username/dist` where you don't have write access.
You can either retry with superuser permissions (i.e. `sudo`) or try something like `brew` instead.

Comment: No luck :( any other ideas?

Comment: Can you check the permissions in the direction in question?

Comment: how do I do that? sorry I am new

Comment: Run `ls -l <the path that comes in the error message>` in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

I had success by changing the properties of the directory where DIST and BUILD folders are created.

Locate and select the directory in Finder and open its porperties window (CMD + I)
Open up the Sharing and permission panel by clicking on the down arrow
Click on the padlock and enter your computer password to make changes
Click on Everyone and then select Read and Write from the dropdown
Click on the small cog and select Apply to enclosed items

Delete the DIST and BUILD folders and try again

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a RedHat 8 OS and have fapolicyd enabled: That will produce this type of error.  You would need to run fapolicyd in debug mode and rerun the command to capture the type of rules that need to be set up within fapolicy.