# how to add an icon to pyinstaller file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make pythonmain.py a executable file using pyinstaller, and I want to add an icon to it;

I tried to add the logo01 png file as the icon option but I still got a file with the default logo:

```
$ pyinstaller --icon=logo01.png pythonmain.py
```

the file still had the default icon,

file: [image]

**update:**

I converted the .png to .ico file as suggested in the comments:

[image]

```
$ pyinstaller --icon=logo01.ico pythonmain.py
```

it deleted the previous folder and made a new executable file, but still with the same default icon;

(file kind is Unix Executable)

Comment: I think you need an ico file.
Also maybe that would help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291113/pyinstaller-setting-icons-dont-change

Comment: Try:
```pyinstaller --onefile --icon=logo01.ico pythonmain.py```

Comment: @David Meu  when I add the option --one file I get a permission error:  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:

Comment: Try removing all files and rerun.
Or change dir permissions (Or run it with sudo).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437879/pyinstaller-permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-users-user-nam

Comment: @David Meu using --onefile worked after I deleted the dist, but still the same default icon is on the file, is there another way to change the icon manually or

Comment: Maybe it's the file not sure.
Try also with --windowed option.
Try some ico file from here:
https://iconarchive.com/tag/linux-.ico

Are you sure ico file exist?

Comment: the .ico file is located in the same folder as the main file. as in the screenshot above^

Comment: do I need to add the absolute path to the .ico or just  the name with the extension because its in the same folder

Comment: just the name with the extension because its in the same folder

Comment: seems like it is a discussed issue for linux (see last):
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2714

Comment: seems it can't be done in linux.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094087/how-to-attach-icon-to-executable-using-pyinstaller-in-archlinux

Comment: if it doesn't work on Mac also then I think I should try another installer

Comment: Oh,
If you are using mac try icns file. As you can see in docs there is only refrence for: windows/mac https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: I converted my icon file to .icns and tried and I used a file from https://iconarchive.com/tag/mac-icns but still the default icon is on the file. :(